# spring oauth2 resourceserver jwt.jwk-set-uri from eureka server

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

Currently i have configured set-uri like below in resource server & spring cloud gateway,

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri: http://dev.auth.server:9999/.well-known/jwks.json
```

However to achieve high availability, I would like to resolve this end point from eureka server, I have successfully registered my auth server in eureka but below configuration  fails,

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri: **lb://auth-server**/.well-known/jwks.json
```

could anyone please suggest?

Comment: Did you find anything on this one?

Comment: @Jodee please find my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

currently there no way to achieve high availability by directly setting auth-server in jwt.jwk-set-uri instead you can achieve this by routing through spring cloud gateway

spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri: **GATEWAY_SERVER_URL**/.well-known/jwks.json

in gateway config, you would have a config like this, which will load balance for you automatically.

```
- id: oauth-server
  uri: lb://auth-server
  predicates:
  - Path=/.well-known/jwks.json
```